# MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(string) not working

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

Here is my code in Visual Studio connected to Unity3d:

```
public void SetupSQLConnection()
{
    Debug.Log("Connection Function Started");
    if (connection == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("If connection == null");
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("Try block started");
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;" + "Database=therapygame;" + "UID=root;" + "Password=;";
            Debug.Log("string set");
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            Debug.Log("new MySqlConnection");
            connection.Open();
            Debug.Log("connection");
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("MySQL Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The Console strings get printed all the way to "string set", but then the rest do not print.

Here is the error in Unity:

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object].get_Item
>   (System.String key) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.get_Database ()
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString
>   (System.String value) MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor
>   (System.String connectionString) (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection:.ctor (string)
>   mysql.SetupSQLConnection () (at Assets/mysql.cs:31) fire_rate.Start ()
>   (at Assets/fire_rate.cs:18)

Comment: I suspect that isn't the exact connection string (obviously you redacted the password).  Have you tried `string connectionString = @"....."` to ignore escape characters?

Comment: Is this client side code or server side code, i ask this because you should not expose your database login information hardcoded in a client side application because off existing decompilers and or disassemblers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                    connBuilder.Server = "localhost";
                    connBuilder.UserID = "root";
                    connBuilder.Database = "therapygame";
                    connBuilder.Password = "";
                    connBuilder.OldGuids = true;

                connection = new MySqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: I responded to your answer with an answer of my own below

Answer (score 0):

@Dhansushka Dayawansha

I implemented your change and I received a new error. I'm happy that I got past the first error! I tried looking for solutions to this new error myself to no avail. Here is the console output:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.Remove (System.String keyword)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Remove (System.String keyword)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringOption.Clean (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.SetValue (System.String keyword, System.Object value)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringOption.<.ctor>b__0 (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder msb, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringOption sender, System.Object value)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item (System.String keyword, System.Object value)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Server (System.String value)
mysql.SetupSQLConnection () (at Assets/mysql.cs:31)
fire_rate.Start () (at Assets/fire_rate.cs:18)
```

Line 31 of mysql.cs:

```
connBuilder.Server = "localhost";
```

Line 18 of fire_rate.cs:

```
GameObject.Find("MySQL").GetComponent<mysql>().SetupSQLConnection();
```