# Connecting MySql in Unity3d -> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

Here is my code in Visual Studio connected to Unity3d:

```
MySqlConnection connection;

MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                connBuilder.Server = "localhost";
                connBuilder.UserID = "root";
                connBuilder.Database = "therapygame";
                connBuilder.Password = "";
                connBuilder.OldGuids = true;

                connection = new MySqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

Here is the error in Unity:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.Remove (System.String keyword)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Remove (System.String keyword)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringOption.Clean (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.SetValue (System.String keyword, System.Object value)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringOption.<.ctor>b__0 (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder msb, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringOption sender, System.Object value)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item (System.String keyword, System.Object value)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Server (System.String value)
mysql.SetupSQLConnection () (at Assets/mysql.cs:31)
fire_rate.Start () (at Assets/fire_rate.cs:18)
```

Line 31 of mysql.cs:

```
connBuilder.Server = "localhost";
```

Line 18 of fire_rate.cs:

```
GameObject.Find("MySQL").GetComponent<mysql>().SetupSQLConnection();
```

This post is an update on a previous issue. Changes in code were made via an answer on that post. Here is the link: [MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(string) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145945/mysqlconnection-new-mysqlconnectionstring-not-working/55187965#55187965)

Comment: Null reference exceptions are always thrown when your application expects some sort of object and finds a null value. Try setting a breakpoint at line 18 and check if your mysql object is null. For further information please refer to this question: 
[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It seems very odd to be getting a `NullReferenceException` (which usually indicates a bug) in `DbConnectionStringBuilder.Remove` (which is a Framework library) from calling `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Server` (which is a pretty common property). Does Unity provide its own version of that library, I wonder? If you can, try switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ an alternative OSS driver for MySQL, because it doesn't use the same ConnectionStringBuilder code path that your exception message shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

> It seems very odd to be getting a NullReferenceException (which
>   usually indicates a bug) in DbConnectionStringBuilder.Remove (which is
>   a Framework library) from calling
>   MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Server (which is a pretty common
>   property). Does Unity provide its own version of that library, I
>   wonder? If you can, try switching to nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector
>   an alternative OSS driver for MySQL, because it doesn't use the same
>   ConnectionStringBuilder code path that your exception message shows.

@Bradley Grainger